# Disable specific puppet environments on puppetmasters

Tags: puppet

Just implemented puppet directory environments on our puppetmasters and I'm looking for a way to disable specific environments.

I have a production and a staging environment and what I want to avoid is someone accidentally running puppet with the staging environment on a production server and vice versa. There is one puppetmaster on each of those environments so I want to disable the "wrong" one on each. They both use the same repo which includes all code.

I'm on puppet 3.8.7 if that's relevant but since we're planning on upgrading soon a solution that works for some other version is also welcome.

Comment: How would someone "accidentally run puppet with the wrong environment" in your setup?

Comment: puppet agent --test --environment <the wrong one>. This is not an outlier, since we used to have a pretty weird setup which we are on the route to fixing we even have automated tools running this on various servers with, for example, the staging environment in production.

Comment: Then you can disable the agent specified override to prevent this.

Comment: That sounds great, but how do I do that? :)

Comment: Puppet Enterprise or free edition?

Comment: The free one <3